# Necesito agregar un radio button dentro de If PHP

Tags: php, botón, radio

Estoy haciendo un sistema de agendamiento de horas y necesito que se muestre un botón de opción, si el registro está vacío, de lo contrario que muestre un texto. Obviamente debo colocar el botón dentro del else del If, pero tengo error con las comillas (disculpen pero soy nuevo en esto). ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?, este es el código:

```
if (empty($row_modera['16:45'])) {
    echo "Horario no disponible";
}
else {
    echo '<input name="16:45" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['nombre']; ?> <?php echo $row_usuario['apellido']; ?>" />'
}
```

El botón de opción toma valor de dos variables (nombre y apellido), gracias por la ayuda.

---

El código es éste (por alguna razón no lo copia completo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

ya no me da error, sin embargo al ejecutar se ve al mismo tiempo la frase y el botón y la idea es que si se cumple o no la condición aparezca una u otra cosa.

Comment: Al parecer no se copio todo el código:

Comment: Tenes que colocar todo el código que tengas dudas entre el ```code``` . Igualmente me parece que falta código para que sepamos como ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
if (empty($row_modera['16:45'])) {
  echo "Horario no disponible";
} else {
  echo '<input name="16:45" type="radio" value="'.$row_usuario['nombre'].' '.$row_usuario['apellido'].'" />';
}
```

edit:
Para concatenar variables en php deberías usar el '.', y no usar las etiquetas de apertura de php si ya las has abierto previamente.